# Why does this Delay future inside poll() not work in my custom Stream type?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to print "Hello" once a second.

Quoting the doc:

> Futures use a poll based model. The consumer of a future repeatedly calls the poll function. The future then attempts to complete. If the future is able to complete, it returns Async::Ready(value). If the future is unable to complete due to being blocked on an internal resource (such as a TCP socket), it returns Async::NotReady.

My `poll` function returns `NotReady` if `Delay`s return is `NotReady`, but nothing is printed to stdout.

```rust
use futures::{Async, Future, Stream}; // 0.1.25
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::timer::Delay; // 0.1.15

struct SomeStream;

impl Stream for SomeStream {
    type Item = String;
    type Error = ();

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Result<Async<Option<Self::Item>>, Self::Error> {
        let when = Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(1000);
        let mut task = Delay::new(when).map_err(|e| eprintln!("{:?}", e));
        match task.poll() {
            Ok(Async::Ready(value)) => {}
            Ok(Async::NotReady) => return Ok(Async::NotReady),
            Err(err) => return Err(()),
        }
        Ok(Async::Ready(Some("Hello".to_string())))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = SomeStream;
    let future = s
        .for_each(|item| {
            println!("{:?}", item);
            Ok(())
        })
        .map_err(|e| {});
    tokio::run(future);
}
```

Comment: Please use `rustfmt` to format the code according to the guidelines of the Rust community. You can find it in the upper right corner of the playground under tools. Also please try to write clear and simple english sentences. It's hard to read your text if there are words missing. I know that english is not everybodys first language (mine neither) and it's hard sometimes. Keep on going!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue here is that state management is missing. You are creating a new `Delay` future every time the stream is polled, rather than holding on to it until it's resolved.
This would lead to never seeing any items coming out of the stream, since these futures are only being polled once, likely yielding `NotReady` each time.

You need to keep track of the delay future in your type `SomeStream`. In this case, one can use an option, so as to also identify whether we need to create a new delay.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct SomeStream {
    delay: Option<Delay>,
}
```

The subsequent code for `SomeStream::poll`, with better error handling and more idiomatic constructs, would become something like this:

```rust
impl Stream for SomeStream {
    type Item = String;
    type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>; // generic error

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Result<Async<Option<Self::Item>>, Self::Error> {
        let delay = self.delay.get_or_insert_with(|| {
            let when = Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(1000);
            Delay::new(when)
        });

        match delay.poll() {
            Ok(Async::Ready(value)) => {
                self.delay = None;
                Ok(Async::Ready(Some("Hello".to_string())))
            },
            Ok(Async::NotReady) => Ok(Async::NotReady),
            Err(err) => Err(err.into()),
        }
    }
}
```

Or, even better, using the `try_ready!` macro, which makes the return of errors and `NotReady` signals with less boilerplate.

```rust
fn poll(&mut self) -> Result<Async<Option<Self::Item>>, Self::Error> {
    let delay = self.delay.get_or_insert_with(|| {
        let when = Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(1000);
        Delay::new(when)
    });

    try_ready!(delay.poll());

    // tick!
    self.delay = None;
    Ok(Async::Ready(Some("Hello".to_string())))
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=799db9aeb7dca75a4cc92fc7026c89bf))